# Get count of documents without loading the whole collection in DerbyJS 0.6

Tags: derbyjs, racerjs, sharejs, livedb

How can I count the results of a query without loading the whole resultset into memory?

The easy way of counting documents returned by a query would be:

```
var q = model.query('mycollection', { date: today });
q.fetch(function() {
    var length = q.get().length;
});
```

But this would load the whole resultset into memory and "count" an array in javascript. When you have lots of data you don't want to do this. I think.

Counting the underlying mongodb collection is rather complicated since LiveDB (I think it is LiveDB) creates many mongodb documents for one derbyjs document.

The internets point to this [google groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/derbyjs/1pcDUKSiuDI) from 2013, but the solution described there *(putting `$count: true` into the query options)* doesn't seem to work in DerbyJS 0.6 and current mongodb.". 
`query.extraRef` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is done like described in the google groups thread. But `query.extraRef` is now `query.refExtra`.

Example:

```
var q = model.query('mycollection', { $count: true, date: today });
q.refExtra('_page.docsOfToday');
q.fetch();
```

Comment: you still want `$count: true` so that you don't fetch all the documents as well